# On Clicking (link) HREF, scroll to top of page in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a page with links (no access to edit links).

Event link as an id at the end of the link. (Eg) 
https://test.com/PageCatalog.aspx?Pcat=16

Earlier the below jquery would work without any issues. I captured the URL and split it exact at = and captured category ID and if I was so an so, I used to sen the scroll to top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url = window.location.href;
        var maid = url.split("=").pop();

        if (maid == 53) {
            $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 10}, 1000);
        }

    });

</script>
```

But now the entire frame work has been update to Angular JS and the above doesn't work. I tried few things but couldn't make it.

Need your help to achieve this in Angularjs.

Comment: I think 53 should be a string btw. `if(maid==="53") {...}`

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Is jquery still included after your Update to Angular? Put console.log inside the if condition to see whether it is entering or not.

Comment: @oel `maid == 53` should work fine.. there something called type coersion.. try it on your console.

Comment: You don't do this in AngularJS, since it's meant for single-page applications, so you would never change the URL like that. Instead, you'd use routing, which would use a completely different technique. Please read some tutorials on AngularJS. You might also consider using Angular instead, as AngularJS is likely to be deprecated.

Comment: It doesn't even execute window.alert(url); So the script is not being read.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's try different approaches and let me know if any of them helped you out:

**The jQuery's method scrollTop()**

The method scrollTop() will return a height value that you can use later.

```
var height =  $(window).scrollTop();
```

**The jQuery's method animate()**

Some times, due how some browsers differ, you will find out that browsers do not respond to the window object, html, or body alone:

```
$(window).scrollTop();
$('html').scrollTop();
$('body').scrollTop();
```

So a way around it is to do an animation affecting both html and body:

```
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0} , 0);
```

The first attribute indicates what property to change.
The second attribute indicates how faster you it should be changed.

**Pure JavaScript**

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

**Using a Anchor + jQuery**

Create an anchor:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Scroll to it:

```
var topTag = $("a[name='top']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: topTag.offset().top}, 0);
```

**Using an Anchor + HREF**

Create an anchor:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Then, scroll to it by pressing on the link:

```
<a href="#top">Go to Top</a>
```